# How to Share .CSV file from Android Wear to Mobile devices

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I would like to share .CSV file from android wearable device (watch) to Android phones. Please help me to solve this requirement.

I searched many forums , but there is no luck.

Thanks 
Priya

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html and select the appropriate API(s).